# How to iterate over a list of string using ko

Tags: knockout.js

So I have the following code to show the warning message forwarded from the backend, which unfortunately isn't working as expected.

```
<div data-bind="with: report">
     <!-- ko foreach: warnings -->
     <div data-bind="text: warnings[index()]"></div>
     <!-- /ko -->
     ...
</div>
```

report is a ko.observable and is filled by a call to the backend that currently returns a warning to notify that something went wrong and prevent a backend crash.

```
report(ko.toJS(data));
```

warnings on the backend is a List in this report class that contains several Lists with objects. Since I don't see any other lists further defined in the js file I would expect the warnigns list to be in report as well, but somehow the messages don't show. Anyone can point me in the right direction to what I'm missing?

Seeing the knockout page with the foreach they only example with objects... So is it possible to even have a simple string array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$data` to refer to the current element of the iteration:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ arrayOfStrings: [ "hello", "world" ] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: arrayOfStrings">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Using `$data` requires a bit of knockout specific knowledge. If you want to circumvent this, I would suggest using the expanded `foreach` binding: `foreach: { data: warnings, as: 'warning' }`:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ warnings: [ "careful!", "watch out!" ] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: warnings, as: 'warning' }">
  <li data-bind="text: warning"></li>
</ul>
```

The reason your current attempt does not work: `foreach` creates a new binding context. `warnings` will no longer be directly accessible, unless it's a property of the subject element of the current iteration. To make it work, you would have to write `$parent.warnings[$index()]`:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ arrayOfStrings: [ "hello", "world" ] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: arrayOfStrings">
  <li data-bind="text: $parent.arrayOfStrings[$index()]"></li>
</ul>
```